# ASP.NET CORE Custom Action Filter Attribute Calling on Controller where it is not applied (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, actionfilterattribute

I am using an Custom Action Filter attribute to check if session is null or not..

**Authenticate.cs**

```
    public class Authenticate : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var data = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserSession");
            if (data == null)
            {
                bool isAjax = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

                if (isAjax)
                {
                    context.Result = new JsonResult("Session Expired!");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Login");
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // our code after action executes
        }
    }
```

I am calling this attribute on all controllers except Account Controller

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        UserFunctions userFunctions;
        public AccountController(ARSContext context)
        {
            userFunctions = new UserFunctions(context);
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(AccountViewModel viewModel)
        {
            User user = userFunctions.Login(viewModel.Username, viewModel.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserSession", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
                return Json(true);
            }
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

My **Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBEntities")));

            services.AddScoped<CountryFunctions>();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Now the main problem is that all of this is working perfectly on my local computer when I run it through Visual Studio. But when I deploy it on IIS what happens is that when I call '/Account/Login' without 'HttpPOST' it shows you view.

But when I submit the form and call '/Account/Login' 'HttpPost' action then My Authenticate filter is called which redirects me back to '/Account/Login' View Action. I also tried to use ServiceFilters but same problem persists.

Comment: Can you try adding `context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` in your `Filter` method and try running on IIS?

Comment: It is not working 
HttpResponse does not contain defination of TrySkipIISCustomErrors

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/IIS/wmi-provider/httperrorssection-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/ . You can also try adding `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` in the web.config

Comment: I think you are not understanding my problem...your solution is telling me how to add custom errors or show response of errors.... actually my problem is not error...its just calling Filter where it should'nt be called

Comment: Okay. Well, in that case could you host in 'local IIS' and debug your code?

Comment: I am debugging it
as i mentioned on calling 'Account/Login' post function it is calling Authenticate function which is redirecting it back to Account/Login get action

Comment: Could you add `[AllowAnonymous]` on your `POST` method and then see what the behavior is?

Comment: Yes i tried that by giving AllowAnnonymous to both controller and action... it is not working.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Nope...in the end I converted my app to ASP.NET MVC